# How to override a control's method, when initialized by FXMLLoader?

Tags: java, javafx, overriding, code-injection, fxmlloader

We have several JavaFX views created with the help of scenebuilder. Their components get injected in controller classes through the `FXMLLoader`, like for example a `TreeTableView`. Now I'd like to override a specific method of `TreeTableView`, but since it gets initialized by `FXMLLoader`, I am not sure how to approach this.

Is there any way to override a method of `TreeTableView` injected by FXMLLoader without creating and importing a new control to scenebuilder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To override a method in SceneBuilder, you need to subclass the target control in Java or some other object oriented language and import your subclass into SceneBuilder.

FXML (on which SceneBuilder is based), is just a declarative system, it doesn't have constructs like subclassing.

Many JavaFX controls have settable event handlers (such as [setOnMouseClicked](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setOnMouseClicked-javafx.event.EventHandler-)) and are also customizable using CSS.  Both of these things can be manipulated in SceneBuilder and FXML.  So there is quite a lot of customization you can do without creating a new control or subclass, but sometimes you may want to create custom controls to get the flexibility you desire.

Comment: I guessed I will have to import these classes into SceneBuilder, since it is not yet about eventhandlers and/or layout specific concerns. It just feels like so much overhead, since I just aim to override a small method to integrate a small enhancement. Anyway thank you for confirming this to me!